# Oracle - How to extract delimited string

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a sample String as below,

```
A|SDFR|RESTA|PRET|PRUQA
B|121|BBCTRI|9ALFA|DEV|5AS
```

I want to extract the part that is coming after send delimiter,

Expected,

```
RESTA|PRET|PRUQA
BBCTRI|9ALFA|DEV|5AS
```

What i got is just extracting single characters regexp_substr

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you mean after the second delimiter, you don't need to use regular expressions for this; you can use the basic ]`substr()`](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions196.htm) function, getting the starting position with [`instr()`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions089.htm):

```
substr(<your_string>, instr(<your_string>, '|', 1, 2) + 1)
```

The third argument to `instr()` says you want the second occurrence; the second argument says you're starting from position 1. That then points to the second delimiter, and you want to start at the next character after that delimiter, so have to add 1.

Demo:

```
with t (str) as (
  select 'A|SDFR|RESTA|PRET|PRUQA' from dual
  union all select 'B|121|BBCTRI|9ALFA|DEV|5AS' from dual
)
select substr(str, instr(str, '|', 1, 2) + 1)
from t;

SUBSTR(STR,INSTR(STR,'|',1
--------------------------
RESTA|PRET|PRUQA
BBCTRI|9ALFA|DEV|5AS
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
substr(string, instr(string, '|', 1, 2)+1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this;

```
with a as (select 'B|121|BBCTRI|9ALFA|DEV|5AS' test from dual)
select substr(test,instr(test,'|',3)+1) from a
```

Comment: That `instr()` call gives you the first delimiter starting from the third character in the string. If the first element isn't always exactly one character (A, B in the example) then this won't always work as expected